# SecurityException Permission Denial MediaProvider READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Tags: android, exception, permissions

i am making gallery.

i got below exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media from pid=23769, uid=10470 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
```

I added permission

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"  />
```

in my AndroidMainfest

my code is below :

```
  Cursor localCursor = MediaStore.Images.Media.query(getContentResolver(), uri, mQuery);
```

i using nexus 5 (android ver 6.0)
help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The permission model changed with Android Marshmallow. You should read this https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html article first! Most of your question will be answered.