# unexpected error while setting a ringtone

Tags: android

I'm trying to set a ringtone with my app. For that I need to write a sound in the external memory of the phone. But every time I try to do it I get this error :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.mtoy.tiboxinshape, PID: 26322
        java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/audio/media from pid=26322, uid=10211 requires android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:476)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1231)
        at com.mtoy.tiboxinshape.SoundAdaptateur$2.onLongClick(SoundAdaptateur.java:142)
        at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:5243)
        at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:21127)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I don't understand why I still have this error as I have the following line in my manifest.xml :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Do you have an idea of what I can do to avoid having this error ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33122512/securityexception-permission-denial-mediaprovider-read-external-storage

Comment: thank you, it helped me to resolve my problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Android changed permission accept in Latest **23 API level**,In This Process Some permission that will be automatically granted at install time those are available for mention in Manifest ,Remaining Permission's Are Accept's in RunTime , Because So many bad guys trying to collect user's personal data through this security weakness So Android Change's to Runtime Permission

For More Information About Runtime Permission's And Process Of Runtime Permisson Accept

**Fallow Below Link**

[Every Android Developer must know about new Android's Runtime Permission](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en)

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution I found :
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html